# Hold button on/off using assembly code using PIC16F887

Tags: assembly, pic, led

I'm using assembly, MPLAP and PROTEUS, to write code turn a LED on or off by a button. The problem here is that my code turns on led when the button in the up position and turns it off when the button at down position.

What I want is: Click the button and the LED turns on and stays on. Click the button again and LED turns off and stays off. Repeat this forever.

Here is my code:

```
; Exam 7 - Bonus 2


INCLUDE "P16F887.INC"
Status  EQU 0x20    ; Bien dung de
BSF     Status,0;


;Init----------------
BANKSEL TRISD   ; Lua chon bank 1
BCF     TRISD,0 ; PortD,0 la Output
CLRF    TRISD
BSF     TRISC,0 ; PortC,0 la Input

BANKSEL PORTD   ; Lua chon bank 0

;Main--------------
check db 0
Start


mainloop


btfsc PORTC,0
GOTO OFF

ON
movlw 0
movwf PORTD
GOTO mainloop



OFF
movlw 1
movwf PORTD
GOTO mainloop



;.............................

END
```

Comment: You need to change your code so it toggles the LED on or off when the input bit changes from 1 to 0.

Comment: @RossRidge Can you write your code ??

Comment: That would seem to be your job. I haven't been given this assignment.

Comment: I have no idea to write something.My teacher just teached me something around operation like add,sub.... And He give me this assignment,

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you will also need to debounce the switch, in this example this is done with a simple delay timer. Be sure to disable the watchdog timer in the configuration bits or add CLRWDT instructions yourself.

```
    INCLUDE "p16f887.inc"

DelayCnt    equ 0x20
DelayCnt2   equ 0x21

    org 0

    ;Init----------------
    BANKSEL TRISD   ; Lua chon bank 1
    BCF     TRISD,0 ; PortD,0 la Output
    CLRF    TRISD
    BSF     TRISC,0 ; PortC,0 la Input

    BANKSEL PORTD   ; Lua chon bank 0

    ;Main--------------

mainloop

    BTFSS PORTC, 0
    GOTO $-1        ;Wait for button to be released

    BTFSC PORTC, 0  
    GOTO $-1        ;Wait for button to be pressed again

    CALL DELAY      ;Wait for button debounce

    BTFSC PORTC, 0
    GOTO mainloop   ;Back to begin if button bounced

    BTFSS PORTD, 0  ;If output is low...
    GOTO SETHIGH    ;Set it.
    BCF PORTD, 0    ;Otherwise clear it.
    GOTO mainloop

SETHIGH

    BSF PORTD, 0
    GOTO mainloop

DELAY           ;Delay function for button debounce
                ;Delays approx 25ms @ 1Mhz instruction clock 
                ;(Fosc = 4Mhz)

    MOVLW 0x20      
    MOVWF DelayCnt2 ;Load 0x20 into DelayCnt2

DELAY_INNER    

    MOVLW 0xFF      
    MOVWF DelayCnt      ;Load 0xFF into DelayCnt
    DECFSZ DelayCnt, F  
    GOTO $-1              ;Decrease DelayCnt until 0

    DECFSZ DelayCnt2, F 
    GOTO DELAY_INNER      ;Run inner loop until DelayCnt2 is 0

    RETURN

    ;.............................

    END
```